# using localtime_s() via pythons's ctype

Tags: python, windows, mingw, ctypes

I wrote a related callback function to use npcap in python.
However, an error occurred while calling the localtime_s() function inside the callback function.

```
libcdll = ctypes.CDLL("msvcrt.dll")

def packet_catpure(interface_info : InterfaceInfo):
    error_buf = (ctypes.c_char * PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE)()
    wpcapdll.pcap_open.restype = ctypes.POINTER(pcap_t)
    pcap_device_handle = wpcapdll.pcap_open(interface_info.name.encode("UTF-8"), 65536, 0, None, error_buf)

    print("listening on {}...".format(interface_info.description))

    callback_func_type = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte), ctypes.POINTER(pcap_pkthdr), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte))
    callback_func = callback_func_type(py_packet_handler)

    wpcapdll.pcap_loop(pcap_device_handle, 0, callback_func, None)

    wpcapdll.pcap_close(pcap_device_handle)


def py_packet_handler(param : ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte), header : ctypes.POINTER(pcap_pkthdr), pkt_data : ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte)):
    ltime = tm()
    timestr = (ctypes.c_char * 16)()
    local_tv_sec = (time_t)()

    local_tv_sec = header.contents.ts.tv_sec
    libcdll.localtime_s(ctypes.byref(ltime), ctypes.byref(local_tv_sec))
    libcdll.strftime(ctypes.byref(timestr), 16, b"%H:%M:%S", ctypes.byref(ltime))

    libcdll.printf(b"%s,%.6d len:%d\n", ctypes.byref(timestr), header.contents.ts.tv_usec, header.contents.len)
```

and error

```
Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function py_packet_handler at 0x000001BF9F9920C0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "task_manager.py", line 436, in py_packet_handler
    libcdll.localtime_s(ctypes.byref(ltime), ctypes.byref(local_tv_sec))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 389, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 394, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: function 'localtime_s' not found
```

I think you are loading the wrong dll. But i don't know what is the correct dll. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

At least in VS2015, `localtime_s` is an inline function that internally calls `_localtime64_s` (from `time.h`):

```c
_Check_return_wat_
static __inline errno_t __CRTDECL localtime_s(
    _Out_ struct tm*    const _Tm,
    _In_  time_t const* const _Time
    )
{
    return _localtime64_s(_Tm, _Time);
}
```

so you can use that name instead:

```py
>>> import ctypes as ct
>>> ct.CDLL('msvcrt')._localtime64_s
<_FuncPtr object at 0x0000020D1A7F4BA0>
```